# How can I get the character code from 'a' to 'z' in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, character

This is what I have currently. However, `?e` shows the character code of the character `e` not the variable e. How to fix it? Thanks.

```
('a'..'z').each {|e| puts ?e}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to output them:

```
(?a..?z).each { |c| puts c.ord }
```

If you just need an array of the 26 numbers.

```
(?a..?z).map(&:ord)
```

Comment: `?a` will not necessarily give you the character code. It will give you the "standard representation of a character" for whatever version of Ruby you are using. So, in Ruby 1.8 and older, it will give you the (ASCII) character code, in Ruby 1.9 and 2.0 it will give you a single character string `'a'`.

Comment: I know, but all my answers assume 1.9+, it's been long enough by now.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
('a'..'z').each {|e| puts e.ord.to_s}
```

Comment: @KulbirSaini Coming from a java background, it sticks on at times. :)

Answer (score 0):

Or even:

```
puts ('a'.ord..'z'.ord).to_a
```